# kendo listview show the value of a nested collection's object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listview, kendo-ui

I have a tablet Object that contain a collection of images, and each image has it's pathProperty,

I have this in my controller

```
public ActionResult Tablettes_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IQueryable<Tablette> tablettes = db.Tablettes;
        DataSourceResult result = tablettes.ToDataSourceResult(request, c => new Tablette
        {
         idProduit=c.idProduit,
         marque=c.marque,
         modele=c.modele,
         prix=c.prix,
         Photos=c.Photos
        });
        var j = Json(result);

        return Json(result);
    }
```

and this is my list view :

```
<div class="demo-section">
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<Tablette>(Model)
        .Name("listView")
        .TagName("div")
        .ClientTemplateId("tablet-widget-template")
        .Pageable()
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
                {
                    dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Tablettes_Read", "Etudiant"));
                    dataSource.PageSize(3);
                })
```

and I want to do something like this

```
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/")#:Photos[0].path#.jpg" 
             alt="#:marque# image" />
```

but i dont understand how :s

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having. What does your current code outputs ? What are you expecting ?

Comment: it doesn't show the items in the listView, and i get this as a console error : http://localhost:6995/Etudiant/Tablettes_Read Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Then your problem lies with the read action, not the template itself. Try debugging the Tablettes_Read method of your Etudiant controller, as it returns a server error.